# Listen to a same port via multiple Docker containers

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, kafka-consumer-api, docker-network

I have brought up a Kafka messaging service where Kafka broker is setup in a docker and is on port 9092. Host port 9092 is mapped to the container port 9092. Now I am trying to bring up a consumer which listens to host port 9092 to consume messages. I'm trying to setup consumer container after all brokers are up using docker compose.

Error I'm getting, when I try to bring up consumer is port 9092 is already allocated

Please someone help me realise whether my approach is right. If its right what can I do to resolve this issue

Comment: If someone connects to the host port 9092, which container do you want that request to map to? Please include any compose files or docker run commands you use.

Comment: You said you're mapping host port 9092 to container port 9092.  If you've already done this, then of course port 9092 is already allocated. You're not going to be able to bring up another container (or any other process) bound to this port.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not just letting the host port be randomly chosen to prevent the collision?

Answer (score 4):

`KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` need to be specified as environment variable with `localhost:<port>`.

By default Kafka listener will listen on 9092 port and when the producer/consumer connects to broker it will advertise the list of brokers as part of Metadata request with the `host:9092`.

Here you are running it in Docker, so host in broker metadata list will be reachable only within the Docker network.

To make it work, we need to make Kafka broker listen on another port, add that to `advertised.listeners` and also add port mapping for the new port.

```
ports:
- "29092:29092"
environment: 
- KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
- KAFKA_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:29092
- KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=EXTERNAL://localhost:29092,INTERNAL://kafka0:9092
- KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=INTERNAL
- KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
```

Comment: See also https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/ for further explanation.

Comment: just out of curiosity, why not just simply exposed port 9092 outside the docker network?